# Tableau: How to restrict a dropdown filter to fields that start with "2021*" (a fiscal week field that adds a new field weekly)?

Tags: filter, dropdown, tableau-api, dashboard

I need an automatic way to have new fiscal weeks (a string that looks like yyyyww) added to my dropdown filter. It's necessary that it's a dropdown unfortunately. Can I just filter out all values that don't start with "2021*" in this particular table? I use those other values in other parts of my dashboard, so I can't filter them out of my data completely.
[image]

Comment: See its other tab `wildcards`

Comment: If the dates are in Tableau date fields then you can just use two filters: one selecting the year and the other selecting discrete weeks (make sure the second only shows relevant values).

Comment: Create a calculated field with the YYYY only. Add it on the filters and it will filter only 2021 data regardless whether you have updated data for 2020, it will show only new updated data for 2021, is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a calculation called DateDisplay as follows:

   IF STARTSWITH((STR([Period])),'2021') = TRUE then 'Display'
   END
2. Add the new DateDisplay field to the Filters Shelf and uncheck NULL
3. Select 'Show Filter' for the string date field
4. On the drop down menu (down arrow on the right) for the filter which is now showing, select the options 'Only Relevant Values'

[image]

Comment: This was actually exactly what I did and it worked beautifully. Thank you!